# What is the difference between typevariable a and b

Tags: haskell

I am learning haskell and one of the tricky part are type variables.
Consider following example:

```
Prelude> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

there is type variables `a` and `b`, they can be any type. And `f` is a type that has to be implemented a Functor.

Lets define a function for first argument for `fmap`:

```
Prelude> let replaceWithP = const 'p'
```

Now, I pass the function `replaceWithP` to `fmap` and looking at the type signature:

```
Prelude> :t fmap replaceWithP
fmap replaceWithP :: Functor f => f b -> f Char
```

Why does `f a` becomes to `f b`, why does it not stay `a`?

Comment: The names printed out by GHCi don't have any special meaning there.

Comment: OK, so `b` can be just any type.

Comment: `a` and `b` may be of different type, but they don't have to. `f` is a polymorphic type that must have the functor constraint.

Comment: So when a function that have following signature `a -> b`, so the type `a` does not have to be different then the type `b`? It can be the same type?

Comment: Firstly, the identity of type variables doesn't correspond to the literal character used to name them except in the local scope of a particular type. So `forall a b . a -> b` and `forall a b . b -> a` are *precisely* the same type. Second, indeed, `a -> b` doesn't mean that `a` and `b` must be different - a type variable can take on any type, including another type variable.

Comment: What does it mean `forall`?

Comment: `forall` is implicitly inserted before parametrized types. A function `a -> String` is actually `forall a. a -> String`, meaning that it works for all types ("for all a, the type is a -> String").

Comment: To understand its type signature it is probably more helpful if you start with a specific `fmap` instance (e.g. for lists: `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`). `f` is `[]` - the parameterized type. `a` of the function domain must correspond to `a` in `[a]` (and so is it with `b`). There is no reason why `a` and `b` must not be of the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the type

```
fmap replaceWithP :: Functor f => f b -> f Char
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
fmap replaceWithP :: Functor f => f a -> f Char
```

because all type variables are implicitly universally quantified, so they can be renamed at will (this is known as alpha-conversion).

One might still wonder where the name `b` printed by GHC comes from. After all, `fmap` had `f a` in its type, so why did GHC choose to rename it as  `b`?

The "culprit" here is `replaceWithP`

```
> :t const
const :: a -> b -> a
> let replaceWithP = const 'p'
> :t replaceWithP 
replaceWithP :: b -> Char
```

So, `b` comes from the type of `replaceWithP`.

Answer (score 3):

Type variables can be thought of normal variables, except you have types instead.

What does this mean? For instance, the variable `a` in C might be defined as:

```
int a = 2;
```

What are the possible values that you could have assigned `a`? The whole `int` range, because that's the set of *values* that `a` may take on. Let's take a look at this in pseudo-Haskell:

```
type b = Int
```

What are the set of values that `b` may take on? That's a trickier question. Typically we're used to seeing things such as `2`, `"hello"`, or `True` as values. However, in Haskell, we also allow types to be treated as values. Sort of. Let's say that `b` can take on any [*kind*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Kind) of form *. Essentially, this includes all types that do not need extra information for their construction:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
Tree      -- no, has kind: * -> *
Tree Int  -- okay!
Int       -- okay!
String    -- okay!
```

This means that in your example:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

The variables `a` and `b` can be thought of variables that can take on types of any form provided that the type you decide to give it is within the appropriate range of type values (as restricted by kinds).

To more precisely answer your question now: why do we observe that:

```
fmap              :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap replaceWithP :: Functor f =>             f b -> f Char
```

Let me rewrite the following equivalent definition, because variable naming can cause confusion:

```
fmap              :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmap replaceWithP :: Functor f =>             f z -> f Char
```

Hopefully this looks more clear now. When you supplied the `replaceWithP :: x -> Char` function, the following mappings occur:

```
-- Function types
fmap         :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
replaceWithP ::              x -> Char

-- Type variable mappings
a -> x
b -> Char
```

What does this look like if we perform substitution?

```
Functor f => (x -> Char) -> f x -> f Char
```

After you have supplied in the `replaceWithP` function, you consume the first parameter, so you're left with:

```
fmap replaceWithP :: Functor f => f x -> f Char
```

Or equivalently:

```
fmap replaceWithP :: Functor f => f b -> f Char
```